# keep server alive after closing command prompt (with forever or forever-monitor)

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, forever, forever-monitor

I'm using Amazon WS to test some rudimentary nodejs server. The problem I'm having is that when I close the putty command prompt on my PC, that I can not reach the server anymore with a browser.

Ive read about forever and forever-monitor. I'n not sure why the script must be restarted constantly, but ok let's assume it must.

I'm using both

```
forever "/home/ec2-user/myApp.js"
```

and

```
node "/home/ec2-user/foreverMonitor.js"
```

(The latter has the myApp.js reference in the foreverMonitor.js file. Similar to [Where place forever-monitor code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26782861/where-place-forever-monitor-code).)

Both do start the server, but when I close putty, both also let the server die.

What am I missing here?

------------------------------------- update -------------------------------------

I guess I can also skip foreverMonitor (not verified yet)

```
nohup forever "/home/ec2-user/myApp.js" &
forever stop "/home/ec2-user/myApp.js"
```

------------------------------------- update -------------------------------------

working, now using this

```
nohup forever "/home/ec2-user/foreverMonitor.js" &
forever stop "/home/ec2-user/foreverMonitor.js"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not totally familiar with AWS, but it seems that you probably need to run [`nohup`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/nohup). The trailing ampersand should give you control of the terminal again immediately after executing the command.

> $ nohup forever "/home/ec2-user/myApp.js" &
>   $ nohup node "/home/ec2-user/foreverMonitor.js" &

See this answer for more details on `nohup` and the trailing ampersand: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15595391/498624

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at PM2 https://github.com/Unitech/pm2

After using forever successfully, I switched to PM2.

forever works fine but I found PM2 was a better fit to my mental model.  PM2 also has a very neat (and repidly evolving) Web interface where you can monitor and control node instances.  As a bonus you can also run non-node tasks under PM2